# R -Smoothscatter plot curve and diagonal axis

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I have file from that wanted plot the smoothscatterplot using R. plot must have the dots, diagonal axis and a curve for that I have formula, I am creating smoothscatterplot but not able plot diagonal and curve any suggestion and help will be appreciated

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KknqYcRBCGm8Xrj1XKh3mE7rb7LK9iny/view?usp=sharing

what I tried

diagonal axis

```
df$P0+df$P2 =1
```

curve

```
p2 = (√df$P0 − 1)^2
```

```
df=read.table("scale_out",sep='\t', header=TRUE)
df = data.frame(df)
smoothScatter(df$P0,df$P2, cex=10)
```

what I got

[image]

what I want

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Your p2 equation is wrong, when p0 = 0, p2 = -2. Also what is the scattering of points on the plot. The actual data points all fall on a line following your red line. There are no points along the blue line or below the red line.

Comment: @dcarlson sorry for my mistake its square of that value not multiplication, p0 =0 will become 1

Comment: @dcarlson for scattering of points on the plot can we use set of values which are in the first column df$genename. a link contains the points wanted (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CMVhyH5_54XGF1cMY2yX5tRwmCeGyJRy/view?usp=sharing))

Answer (score 0):

The data doesn't seem to contain what you think it contains.

For example, if we just do a straight plot of P0 and P2, we get this:

```r
plot(df$P0, df$P2, pch = 18, cex = 0.5)
```

[image]

The desired plot that you show in your question suggests that this should be a scatter plot of noisy data, but it isn't. If we plot all the numeric variables in your data frame against each other, we get this:

[image]

The only plot here that looks like a scatter plot of the correct shape is `P0` versus `B.prop`.

Assuming that this is what you want, you can create the desired plot like this:

```r
smoothScatter(df$P0, df$B.prop, cex = 2, xlab = "P0", ylab = "P2")
curve((sqrt(x) - 1)^2, 0, 1, lty = 2, lwd = 5, col = "red", add = TRUE)
lines(0:1, 1:0, lty = 2, lwd = 5, col = "deepskyblue4")
legend(0.35, 1, c("Coordination", "Independence"), 
       col = c("deepskyblue4", "red"), bg = "#FFFFFFAA", 
       lty = 2, lwd = 5, box.col = "#FFFFFF00")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your Valuable response answer my question, I will take a look into my data again, can you tell me is it posible to get points near to blue line and red curve.